# Disabling state provider behavior for certain anchor tags in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, session-state-provider

I have an Angular SPA that is working fine when using $stateProvider however I am having issues with some anchor tags which are causing view to be changed to default behavior `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");`

For example I want following anchor tag not to change state when clicked on it since it is only used for Carousel.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#webTemplates" role="button" data-slide="prev">
```

Is there a way to ignore certain anchor tags using directives or some other technique. My $stateProvider code is below.

```
$stateProvider
.state("home", { url: "/home", templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "myviews/home.html" })
.state("about", { url: "/about", templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "myviews/about.html" })
.state("contact", { url: "/contact", templateUrl: baseTemplateUrl + "myviews/contact.html" })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");
```

Comment: You can always leave href as blank, which wouldnt trigger any state transition.

Comment: @MuthukannanKanniappan that's not an option for certain anchor tags as per my example of carousel. You have to have something in anchor tags for carousel to work.

Comment: Use a more angular friendly carousel that doesn't require a hash in href. or modify the carousel script to prevent default

Comment: @charlietfl I believe both are not feasible options since carousel left right arrows wouldn't work without href and "#" specifies the id, and carousel is default Bootstrap carousel and I don't want to modify default bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Well there's a big part of the issue using `bootstrap.js` and not using an angular friendly one like `angular-ui-bootstrap` or any number of other carousels. No idea why it's not feasible to develop page without jQuery and bootsrap.js dependencies